# Updating Dependency for ORML

Tags: pallet, runtime

I have the responsibility of updating an old pallet (1-2 years old) and I can not find an updated directory since currently it is throwing this error:

```
error: failed to select a version for `parity-util-mem`.
    ... required by package `sp-runtime v3.0.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `sp-runtime = "^3.0.0"` of package `frame-support v3.0.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `frame-support = "^3.0.0"` of package `orml-utilities v0.4.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `orml-utilities = "^0.4.0"` of package `pallet-vesting v3.0.0 (/Users/jackson/Desktop/chain_v2/pallets/vesting)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `pallet-vesting` (locked to 3.0.0) of package `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/jackson/Desktop/chain_v2/runtime)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `node-template-runtime` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/Users/jackson/Desktop/chain_v2/node)`
versions that meet the requirements `^0.9.0` are: 0.9.0

the package `parity-util-mem` links to the native library `parity-util-mem-ban-duplicates`, but it conflicts with a previous package which links to `parity-util-mem-ban-duplicates` as well:
package `parity-util-mem v0.10.2`
    ... which satisfies dependency `parity-util-mem = "^0.10.2"` of package `sc-informant v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=devhub/latest#22d40c76)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `sc-informant` (locked to 0.10.0-dev) of package `sc-service v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=devhub/latest#22d40c76)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `sc-service` (locked to 0.10.0-dev) of package `frame-benchmarking-cli v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=devhub/latest#22d40c76)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-benchmarking-cli` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/Users/jackson/Desktop/chain_v2/node)`
Only one package in the dependency graph may specify the same links value. This helps ensure that only one copy of a native library is linked in the final binary. Try to adjust your dependencies so that only one package uses the links ='parity-util-mem' value. For more information, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#links.

failed to select a version for `parity-util-mem` which could resolve this conflict
```

This is the import statement I am using in the toml: `orml-utilities = { version = "0.4.0", default-features = false }`

Answer (score 2):

You need to check out which Substrate version that you are upgrading to.

Then replace all runtime dependencies' Substrate version to that version.

Finally, you can check the `Cargo.lock` to find out which dependency is using an incompatible parity-util-mem.

Note:
I suggest following a release branch. Like:

```
# your project.toml
polkadot-xxx = { git = "...polkadot", branch = "release-v0.9.25 }
cumulus-xxx = { git = "... cumulus", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25 }
substrate-xxx = { git = "... substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25 }
```

Otherwise, you might need to select the version manually.
If you change the dependencies to an untagged/unbranched version, it might break the compatibility.