# error: failed to select a version for `parity-db`

Tags: parachain, frontier, cumulus

I was trying to add Frontier as a dependency of my parachain(Substrate Cumulus based) project...

```
$ cargo build -r       
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/PNetwork/frontier`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/frontier`
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for `parity-db`.
    ... required by package `fc-db v2.0.0-dev (https://github.com/PNetwork/frontier?branch=patch3-polkadot-v0.9.25#2e4daa4e)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `fc-db` of package `fc-cli v1.0.0-dev (https://github.com/PNetwork/frontier?branch=patch3-polkadot-v0.9.25#2e4daa4e)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `fc-cli` of package `parachain-template-node v0.1.0 (/mnt/sda3/polkadot/substrate-parachain-template-evm/node)`
versions that meet the requirements `^0.3.14` are: 0.3.16, 0.3.15, 0.3.14

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `parity-db v0.3.13`
    ... which satisfies dependency `parity-db = "^0.3.13"` (locked to 0.3.13) of package `polkadot-node-subsystem-util v0.9.25 (https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot?branch=release-v0.9.25#5174e9ae)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `polkadot-node-subsystem-util` (locked to 0.9.25) of package `polkadot-approval-distribution v0.9.25 (https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot?branch=release-v0.9.25#5174e9ae)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `polkadot-approval-distribution` (locked to 0.9.25) of package `polkadot-service v0.9.25 (https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot?branch=release-v0.9.25#5174e9ae)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `polkadot-service` (locked to 0.9.25) of package `cumulus-relay-chain-inprocess-interface v0.1.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus?branch=polkadot-v0.9.25#390042a0)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `cumulus-relay-chain-inprocess-interface` (locked to 0.1.0) of package `parachain-template-node v0.1.0 (/mnt/sda3/polkadot/substrate-parachain-template-evm/node)`

failed to select a version for `parity-db` which could resolve this conflict
```

I was using https://github.com/PNetwork/frontier repo to replace https://github.com/paritytech/frontier because I need to change the Frontier repo's substrate version to polkadot-v0.9.25, which is the same substrate version in my parachain.

My project/node/Cargo.toml

```
# Frontier
fc-cli = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier", branch = "master" }
fc-consensus = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier", branch = "master" }
fc-db = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier", branch = "master" }
fc-mapping-sync = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier", branch = "master" }
fc-rpc = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier", branch = "master" }
fc-rpc-core = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier", branch = "master" }
fp-consensus = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier", branch = "master" }
fp-dynamic-fee = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier", branch = "master" }
fp-evm = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier", branch = "master" }
fp-rpc = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier", branch = "master" }
fp-storage = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier", branch = "master" }

# Cumulus
cumulus-client-cli = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }
cumulus-client-collator = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }
cumulus-client-consensus-aura = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }
cumulus-client-consensus-common = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }
cumulus-client-network = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }
cumulus-client-service = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }
cumulus-primitives-core = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }
cumulus-primitives-parachain-inherent = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }
cumulus-relay-chain-inprocess-interface = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }
cumulus-relay-chain-interface = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }
cumulus-relay-chain-rpc-interface = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }
```

then I tried to fix this parity-db version:

```
cargo update -p parity-db --precise 0.3.14
```

then it became `error: failed to select a version for tokio`
then I tried to fix it:

```
cargo update -p tokio --precise 1.19.2
```

then it went back to `error: failed to select a version for parity-db`

I cannot change the dependency at https://github.com/PNetwork/frontier,
so I think I need to somehow specify the version of `cumulus-relay-chain-inprocess-interface`. Right?

How can I do that so the parity-db is somehow pumped up in version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Updating Dependency for ORML](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3868/updating-dependency-for-orml/3875#3875).

---

And this is what we do https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/main/runtime/darwinia/Cargo.toml.

Lock all the different repositories' Substrate to a single version `darwinia-v0.12.3`.

In your code, that `master` branch not always matches `polkadot-v0.9.25`.

Comment: Thank you. I was also patching dependencies and use other project's Cargo.lock... After removing target folder and Cargo.lock for file regeneration, it works